# Substring Without any Allocation Using Span<T>

Tags: c#, string, performance, memory, substring

How can we use `Span<T>` instead of `string.Substring` in order to eliminate the necessity of heap allocation? Let's say we have the following code:

```
var firstNameAndFamilyName="myname,myfamily";
var span = firstNameAndFamilyName.AsSpan().Slice(0,6);
var firstName = .... //  How can I get 'myname' without allocating any new memory on the heap?
```

Please note that I know that the string `"myname,myfamily"` is located on the heap and `firstName` needs to point to somewhere in the heap. ***My question is that how can we point to a subset of a string without coping that part to a new location of heap memory?***

I know that a new constructor has been added to the String class which accepts [`ReadOnlySpan<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=netcore-2.1#System_String__ctor_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__) like:

```
var firstName = new string(span);
```

But I couldn't find anywhere whether it's done by allocating on the heap or not.

Comment: With `new string(…)` you are getting brand new `string` object, which have to be allocated somewhere. And as it can outlive current method, it can not be allocated on stack.

Comment: @PetSerAl `Span<T>` is located on the stack but its contents could be on the heap. So, by using `new string(span)`, we are creating a pointer which can point to somewhere in the heap.

Comment: Is your question - is the `new string` assigned to `firstName` allocated on the heap? If so, the answer is yes - strings are always allocated on the heap. My follow up question is - why do you care? What is your underlying problem? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Or are you asking about the `span` (which is a different question altogether)?_

Comment: @mjwills I want to know if `new string(span)` copies data from `span` to another part of heap memory or not.

Comment: Simple test, after `var firstName = new string(span)` modify the span and let us know what happens to the string you created, you will answer your question

Comment: *somewhere in the heap* Like what exactly? String object have specific format, which does not just emerge from nothing. Possible it return the same `string`, when the `Span` represent whole string, but I am doubt that such even allowed.

Comment: `I want to know if new string(span) copies data from span to another part of heap memory or not` Yes - it does.

Comment: So you just want to use a slice of your span (**as a string**) and not allocate a string?

Comment: @TheGeneral, yep, basically I want to know if it's possible to get a slice of my span as a string, without coping that part to another location.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you are well aware, `System.String` [is immutable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?#Immutability). No buts, no ifs. If you have a `Span<char>` and want to treat them as `string`, new memory will be allocated.

The good news is that with the introduction of `Span<>`, *many of the built-in methods in the framework have been updated to accept it*, in addition to accepting  strings and arrays. To quote [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx) (I've added links to some examples):

> .. many such methods have been added across the framework. From [`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextbytes?view=netcore-2.1#System_Random_NextBytes_System_Span_System_Byte__) to [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.append?view=netcore-2.1#System_Text_StringBuilder_Append_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Char__) to [`System.Net.Sockets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.send?view=netcore-2.1#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Send_System_ReadOnlySpan_System_Byte__), overloads have been added to make working with `{ReadOnly}Span<T>` and `{ReadOnly}Memory<T>` simple and efficient.

This also includes all the numeric `{Try}Parse(string)` methods which will now have corresponding `(ReadOnlySpan<char>)` [overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.parse?view=netcore-2.1).

```
var str = "123,456";
var span = str.AsSpan(0,3);
var i = int.Parse(span); // 123
```

So instead of getting a `string` out of your spans, see if what you're trying to achieve can utilise the `Span<>` directly.

Comment: Technically strings in C# are only immutable by "social construct". Using unsafe fixed code, they are totally mutable. Now, as that unsafe key word suggests, that's not entirely safe in all contexts, e.g. if the string is used by other simultaneously executing code, or if it was interned, but if you checked both of these, it's pretty much mutable. And if you offset your pointer to one int in front of the data, you can also trim down the length...

Comment: The C# view of a string is immutable. You're correct with your comment about `unsafe`, but in 15 years of C# development I haven't used it. It's not what I'd call an everyday tool in my programming tool belt.